# Enviar por Ajax informação de uma td quando usuário alterar o campo de Select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, html-select

Olá, tenho a seguinte tabela construída com valores vindo do BD, e após o JS para realizar a função após alteração no campo de Select

```
<tr>
            <td class="idCarga" style="display:none;"><?php echo odbc_result($result, "Id");?></td>
            <td class="editavel"><?php echo odbc_result($result, "Data Exp.");?></td>
            <td class="editavel"><?php echo odbc_result($result, "Data Agend.");?></td>
            <td><?php echo odbc_result($result, "Nº Carga");?></td>
            <td><?php echo odbc_result($result, "Tipo Carga");?></td>
            <td class="editavel"><?php echo odbc_result($result, "Rota");?></td>
            <td class="editavel"><?php echo odbc_result($result, "Carga SAP");?></td>
            <td class="editavel"><?php echo odbc_result($result, "Carro-Viagem");?></td>
            <td><?php echo odbc_result($result, "Operação");?></td>
            <td class="editavel"><?php echo odbc_result($result, "Região");?></td>
            <td>
              <select onchange="getStatus(this);">
                <?php 
                $valorStatus = odbc_result($result, "Status");

                if ($valorStatus == 'Parada') {
                ?>
                <option value="1">Parada</option>
                <option value="2">Expedida</option>
                <option value="3">Cancelada</option>
                <?php
                }elseif ($valorStatus == 'Expedida') {
                ?>
                <option value="1">Parada</option>
                <option value="2" selected>Expedida</option>
                <option value="3">Cancelada</option>
                <?php
                }elseif ($valorStatus == 'Cancelada') {
                ?>
                <option value="1">Parada</option>
                <option value="2">Expedida</option>
                <option value="3" selected>Cancelada</option>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
              </select> 
...
```

JS

```
function getStatus(sel){
          var idStatus = (sel.value);
                  $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../Control/updateControleCargas.php",
            data: {
            id: $('td.idCarga').parent().children().first().text(),
            campoStatus: idStatus
            }
          })
}
```

Ao realizar a troca no Select, a função do onChange é chamada, nela eu consigo obter tranquilamente o valor do campo que foi alterado (com sel.value), porém não estou conseguindo trazer o valor da <td class="idCarga".
Estou tentando com "$('td.idCarga').parent().children().first().text()" mas sempre me traz o valor da primeira "tr", e não da "tr" onde foi feita a alteração do select, o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Experimenta trocar `$('td.idCarga').parent().children().first().text()`por `$(sel).parents('tr').find('td.idCarga').text()`.

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado @Benilson

Comment: Ainda bem que deu certo. 

Answer (score -2):

Conforme informado pelo @Benilson, funcionou trocando $('td.idCarga').parent().children().first().text()
POR
$(sel).parents('tr').find('td.idCarga').text().

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).